# Show, sort , and limit by products based on subcategory on category page

Tags: category, sorting

How do I sort products on a category page by subcategory as well as limit the number of products from each subcategory:

For example if the category was Food I would want to display the following:

Drinks
Coke 12oz, Orange Juice 8oz, Milk Gallon,

Pasta,
Spaghetti 1lb, Pesto 12 pc, Tortellini 1 PC.

And so on, displaying each subcategory name followed 3 products (images etc.)

I currently have a custom template that displays the subcategories but can't figure out the products. Here is my current code:

```
<?php
    $_category = $this->getCurrentCategory();
    $collection = $_category->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(
            array('url_key','name','all_children','is_anchor','description','image')
        )
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
        ->addIdFilter($_category->getChildren())
        ->setOrder('position', 'ASC')
        ->joinUrlRewrite();

    $helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
?>

<ul>
<?php foreach ($collection as $cat): ?>
<li>
    <div class="level1descript">
        <a href="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($cat); ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $cat->getImageUrl(); ?>" class="catlevel1image" />
            <h2><?php echo $cat->getName(); ?></h2>
        </a>
        <p class="level1descript">
        <?php
            $catdesc = '';
            $catdesc = strip_tags($cat->getDescription());
            if (strlen($catdesc) > 300) {
                $catdesc = substr($catdesc, 0, 300) . ' ...';
            }
            echo $catdesc;
        ?>
        </p>
    </div>
    <?php 

        $childLevel2Category = $cat->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect(
                array('url_key','name','all_children','is_anchor','description','image')
            )
            ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
            ->addIdFilter($cat->getChildren())
            ->setOrder('position', 'ASC')
            ->joinUrlRewrite();
    ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($childLevel2Category as $catLevel2) { ?>
        <li class="level2cats">
            <a href="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($catLevel2); ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $catLevel2->getImageUrl(); ?>" class="catlevel2image" />
                <h4><?php echo $catLevel2->getName(); ?></h4>
            </a>
            <p class="level2descript">
            <?php
                $catdesc = '';
                $catdesc = strip_tags($catLevel2->getDescription());
                if (strlen($catdesc) > 60) {
                    $catdesc = substr($catdesc, 0, 60) . ' ...';
                }
                echo $catdesc;
            ?>
        </li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</li>
<?php endforeach;?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you mean sort collection by category id, check this you may need to modify this code:

```
$products = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/product' )
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect( '*' )
    ->addFieldToFilter( 'status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED )
    ->addFieldToFilter( 'visibility', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH );
    ->addAttributeToFilter( 'category_id', array( 'in' => array( 'finset' => '[CATEGORY_ID_HERE]' ) ) );
    ->addAttributeToSort( 'category_id', ASC )
    ->addAttributeToSort( 'name', ASC );
```